# Selenium with Chrome works for one user, but not another

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I have two users on Ubuntu 22.04. They both have the same packages in their virtual environments with Python 3.10.12.

```
selenium==4.2.0
webdriver-manager==4.0.1
```

They are both able to execute `chrome`:

```
$ ls -al /opt/google/chrome/chrome
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 229088456 Sep 20 23:10 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

For one of them, the below runs okay, while for the other, I get an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

wdm = ChromeDriverManager()

selenium = webdriver.Chrome(wdm.install(), options=options)
```

Error for the second user:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/testing/testing/testing_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x559104ccb6b3 <unknown>
#1 0x5591049a11e7 <unknown>
#2 0x5591049d4526 <unknown>
#3 0x5591049d069c <unknown>
#4 0x559104a1323a <unknown>
#5 0x559104a09e93 <unknown>
#6 0x5591049dc934 <unknown>
#7 0x5591049dd71e <unknown>
#8 0x559104c90cb8 <unknown>
#9 0x559104c94bf0 <unknown>
#10 0x559104c9f19c <unknown>
#11 0x559104c95808 <unknown>
#12 0x559104c6227f <unknown>
#13 0x559104cb9e88 <unknown>
#14 0x559104cba059 <unknown>
#15 0x559104cca843 <unknown>
#16 0x7f8c8ba94b43 <unknown>
```

Any ideas what I could check to track down this error? Maybe the environments are different or there is a conflict between two Chrome instances, but I don't know what else to check.

Comment: Usually it means you need to kill not closed chromium instance(s).

Comment: Hm... `ps aux | grep chrom` returns nothing. There is no running chrome or chronium process.

Comment: Can you try headless mode if you are in non headless or the opposite?